# How can I allow users to add options to a product listing from a coding perspective?

Tags: reactjs

Creating an eCommerce type react application and part of it is merchants can create product listings(item title, item description, item price, etc). How do I allow them to add options to the listing like Size, Color, etc. It seems more confusing than just having input fields that can change a state variable.

An example of what a completed array should look like after a user enters options:

```
const options = [
 {
  optionName: 'Size', 
  values: ['small', 'medium', 'large']
}, 
{
  optionName: 'Color', 
  values: ['blue', 'black', 'white', 'tan'],
}
]
```

Above is how it should be constructed to be sent to server.

Let me know if any more clarification is needed.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is `dynamic form construction`, and is always much more complicated than a static form. This is not an easy feature to implement.

What you've sketched out there as dummy API request data is essentially the solution -- you just need to provide UI that enables that solution. Presumably you have an object that holds all your form data, so you can add a field like `userDefinedOptions` that gets initialized with an empty array.

Then, you'll need UI elements to allow adding a new user-defined option, which will probably include the display name of the option, as well as the list of choices for that option. This UI would then call an event handler that inserts the inputted values into your list of user-defined options.

Dynamic forms can get very messy very fast, so I'd recommend looking into a form library to handle some of the overhead. You'll also need to validate the dynamic user data before sending it off to the API.

Hope that helps!